How to temporarily work on two dependant Nuget projects locally?
I have two C# libraries A and B that usually are developed and versioned independently. Both have their own Git repos and each is published to a central Nuget repository. B depends on A.
Now I have a bug that affects and needs to be fixed in both projects. For this, I need to work locally on both projects and especially I need to change project A without publishing it to the central Nuget repo.
What is the standard approach or workflow to temporarily use the local version of project A from project B? Do you typically use version numbers to select the local version?
I am using JetBrains Rider, if possible I would like to use Rider functionality to do this switch.
I have a Java/Maven background, there I would use a SNAPSHOT version for project A, publish it to the local Maven repo and use that version for the dependency in project B.
I did it succesfully in a similar way using version numbers. But originally and differently from Maven, here the number of the own version is not included in the source. So I doubt this is the "standard approach" in C# / Nuget.

Maybe you can reference Project A in Project B instead of using the NuGet package. In JetBrains Rider, right-click Project B, select "Add Reference," and choose Project A. This allows Project B to use the local version of Project A without modifying the version. or...maybe you can set up a local NuGet feed to test unpublished changes.

"But originally and differently from Maven, here the number of the own version is not included in the source" - I don't know what you mean by that. I'd expect it to be in the project file, so it's easy to specify a "local development" one. (That's what I normally do - I create "1.3.0-jon01" or similar, copy it to my local nuget folder, and test that way.)

@RCat: Referencing A from B without using Nuget is probably not possible because of transitive dependencies.

@Jon Skeet: I do not know why the version number is not present, but it is not. Probably it is added somewhere in the Azure build pipeline.

@Jon Skeet: basically thats what I did (as there was no version number, I added one temporarily)
